# Combining two cat statements into a single cat statement within bash

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I want to combine 2 different `cat` statements into a single `cat` statement

```
cat /dir1/file1.cfg | grep -q "linux"

cat /dir1/file2.cfg | grep -q "linux"
```

is there an `OR` operation that can be used here to do the `grep -q "linux"` on 2 files?

Comment: In this case, why not just use: `cat /dir1/file*.cfg | grep -q "linux"`?

Comment: That is the original function of `cat`: To **conCATenate** and print files. In this case, you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) and do `cat /dir1/file{1..2}.cfg | grep -q "linux"`

Comment: As mentioned above -- if you *don't* want to concatenate multiple files, you **shouldn't be using `cat` at all**; it's much more efficient to give `grep` a direct handle on the files to search rather than forcing it to read from a FIFO connected to a separate process that is itself responsible for reading from the files. (With `grep`, actually, it may or may not be that significant -- but for `wc -c`, or `sort`, or `tail`, or other programs that can parallelize, seek, bisect, or otherwise use optimized implementations when given a real file handle the difference can be huge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

How about:

`cat /dir1/file1.cfg /dir1/file2.cfg | grep -q "linux"`

or with a subshell:

`(cat /dir1/file1.cfg; cat /dir1/file2.cfg) | grep -q "linux"`

or just:

`grep -q "linux" /dir1/file1.cfg /dir1/file2.cfg`

Comment: cat is literally short for concatenate. you can just do `cat file1 file2 | grep ...`

Comment: `{ cat ...; cat ...; }` would be slightly more efficient than `(cat ...; cat ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

These all give equivalent results. The last would be how I'd write it.

```
% (cat f1; cat f2) | grep -q "linux"
% (cat f1 f2) | grep -q "linux"
% grep -q "linux" f1 f2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for `cat` at all - `grep` will happily take its input from multiple files; normally, you need to tell it not to prefix the file name to the output lines, but since you're using `-q`, even that isn't necessary:

```
grep -q "linux" /dir1/file[12].cfg
```

(I've used a shell glob to save writing the repeated parts of the filename there).